# inline lambda function using cdk

Tags: aws-cdk

This code is working as expected and I can create cloudformation template. But I need to embed the function inline. This sample code will upload the file to S3 and I do not want to use S3.

> ```
> # cat mylambda/hello.py
> ```

```
import json

def handler(event, context):
    print('request: {}'.format(json.dumps(event)))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        'body': 'Hello, CDK! You have hit {}\n'.format(event['path'])
    }
```

> ```
> # cat app.py
> ```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from aws_cdk import core
from hello.hello_stack import MyStack

app = core.App()
MyStack(app, "hello-cdk-1", env={'region': 'us-east-2'})
MyStack(app, "hello-cdk-2", env={'region': 'us-west-2'})

app.synth()
```

> ```
> # cat hello/hello_stack.py
> ```

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
)

class MyStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # Defines an AWS Lambda resource
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            code=_lambda.Code.asset('mylambda'),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of inline lambda function that can be deployed using cdk

```
git clone https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples.git

mkdir lambda-cron1
cd lambda-cron1

cdk init --language python

cp /tmp/aws-cdk-examples/python/lambda-cron/* .

pip install -r requirements.txt

export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx

cdk ls

cdk synth LambdaCronExample  > a2.txt

cdk deploy  LambdaCronExample
```